# How to prevent over-tightening a bolt with a socket wrench?

Tags: tools

I recently bought a socket wrench to fix a loose and awkwardly positioned bolt on my mountain bike. The bolt secures the bike's crank arm to the frame of the bike. How do I ensure I don't over-tighten the bolt and break it?

Comment: Crank arm?  Do you mean the arm to which the the pedals bolt?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, the size and grade of the bolt will indicate its strength and the max torque that should be applied. You can use a torque wrench (they make them rated for inch-pounds and foot-pounds) to set the amount of torque you want to apply to the bolt.

If your bike has a service manual, it may specify the torque settings there. Otherwise, the bolt may have markings on the head indicating the size and grade of the bolt.

Comment: Don’t tighten to the limit provided by the grade of the bolt. Go to half or 2/3 as those cranks are usually on a taper.

Answer (score 4):

If that nut was loose there is a high chance of the problem recurring, especially if the crank was slightly loose while riding. Yes, it should be very tight, once you find out how tight you can put a lever on the arm of the wrench, and carefully put a weight on the end to get the exact tightness.

For example, 305 inch-pounds (34 Newton-metres) is exerted by a lever approximately one metre long with 3.4 kg weight at the end, holding horizontally. Or 25 pounds on a one foot long lever.

There is a bicycle site too at: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com
Some sample recommended tightnesses I got from the parktools website are below.

Crank bolt tightness in inch-pounds
Shimano 305-391
Campagnolo®312-324
FRA® (M8 bolt) 304-347
FRA® (M14 steel) 434-521
Race Face® 480
Syncros®240
Truvativ® 384-420
ISIS Drive Truvativ® 336-372 square type
White Ind® 240-300